# Can't get html elements to be on the same line

Tags: html, css, layout, positioning, drop-down-menu

I have this page: http://www.problemio.com which has a black bar on top which has search and a dropdown menu.  That looks reasonably ok.

But then I have another page like this: http://www.problemio.com/category.php?category_id=1 which has those two elements, but for some reason, the search appears on the top left of the bar.

How can I make these elements appear as they do on the home page of problemio.com ?

Thanks!

Comment: You have the same markup like on the home page. Just include styles fro these element on this page. (actually you need to add `float:left`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it absolutely positioned over your search box. Fix the absolute positioning and you should be fine.

Comment: which relative style are you referring to? Thanks!

Comment: This element: <div class=​"menusystem" id=​"site_nav"> You have it absolutely positioned

Comment: If you remove the absolute positioning, the right positioning, the top positioning and float it right, it starts to look correct. Try that and adjust to suit your needs.

Comment: thanks, I mostly got it right with your help, but I still for some reason have the dropdown way over on the left side. Which css direction should I adjust to make them line up one after one to the right?  Thanks!!

Comment: Use relative positioning to position child elements relative to their parent elements. That should help you out. Look up some son-of-suckerfish CSS styling, that might help you out.

Comment: Accept my answer if you feel it helped you :)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have you `main_styles.css` on the interior page, which has this style in it:

```
#search {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 7px;
    width: 14em;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - just made the adjustment, but the elements now overlap each other. Any idea what else is wrong? :)

Answer (score 1):

In your page which displays the search box as you desire [problemio.com] the div has the css value 'float: right'. This is the value you need on the other page.

```
div#search {
float: right
}
```

Comment: thanks - but now the elements just overlap each other. Any idea what is still not right with the page? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I just answered this in the comments of your other question, posted 5 min ago.
Your problem is that the home page div with class `nav` takes values from `main_index.css` and the other page takes values from `main.css`.
There are some inconsistencies between the two which might lead to the problem. Firebug or devtools will help you debug these kind of problems.

Comment: thanks, saw that! I just made the adjustment, but still something is off - the two elements now overlap each other.  Any idea what else is missing? Thanks!!